# Omitting generic parameters after the new keyword

Tags: java, generics

Is there any difference between the two lines?

```
SomeClassOrInterface<Type1> name = new SomeClass<Type1>();
SomeClassOrInterface<Type1> name = new SomeClass<>();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second syntax is only valid on Java 7 whereas the former is valid on Java 5+